# Unable to googleSignIn with firebase - android

Tags: android, firebase

i am working on googleSignIn with firebase

my app-build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        // applicationID,sdk version etc
    }
    buildTypes {
        // release, debug etc
    }
}
dependencies {
// other dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}
```

& my project-build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my signInButton

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_activity_google_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

my java code

```
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_activity_google_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();
            GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(SignInActivity.this, gso);
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Misc.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
```

and onActivityResult

```
if (requestCode == Misc.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Log.e("signInResult:name", account.getDisplayName());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.e("signInResult:failed", "code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            Misc.showAlert(SignInActivity.this, "Google Sign in", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

i tried my best to do exactly as they say in firebase docs[here []](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), but something doesn't seems to be working right,,, because i always get exception with response code `10`, which by searching i found that it might be caused by configuration, my project is set in firebase app,,, and i am very sure that it should be ok,, because if i try to do `signInWithEmailAndPassword` it works, but for `GoogleSignIn` it doesn't seem to be working, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: did you add sha1 code in firebase?

Comment: yes i did,,, also i got google-services.json file from that same place as well

Comment: check my answer. Replace with my code.

Comment: Did you add Debug key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set your sha keys for both environments (release & debug)

you can run this command to get the sha key,

for release

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

and then for debug key

```
keytool -list -v \-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore(password for debug keystore is >>>>android<<<)
```

make sure to have both codes in your firebase projects, i believe you have either set wrong `sha` or you are missing one of them

Answer (score 0):

Check this Out :

Add this inside `oncreate`:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                    .build();
signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
```

Out side of `oncreate():`

```
 private void signIn() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing In Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess())
            {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                assert account != null;

                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    }
```

Lastly :

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information






                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Toast.makeText(LRActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });





}
```

Comment: i have tried with this,,, i get `statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR`  on result.getStatus()

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).